# howt to use mBagOfTags in ViewModel android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, viewmodel, package-private

I have object that implement Closeable interface and want to close() method called when my ViewModel is clear. I know to implement onCleared method of ViewModel but I want to use mBagOfTags in ViewModel. mBagOfTags handle closeable object (call close method in clear method) and don't want create new map object in ViewModel . How can I use mBagOfTags of ViewModel ??

mBagOfTags and their member functions  in ViewModel are package Private access modifer.

this is the ViewModel class that android team is developed.

```
package androidx.lifecycle;

public abstract class ViewModel {
// Can't use ConcurrentHashMap, because it can lose values on old apis (see b/37042460)
@Nullable
private final Map<String, Object> mBagOfTags = new HashMap<>();
private volatile boolean mCleared = false;

/**
 * This method will be called when this ViewModel is no longer used and will be destroyed.
 * <p>
 * It is useful when ViewModel observes some data and you need to clear this subscription to
 * prevent a leak of this ViewModel.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
protected void onCleared() {
}

@MainThread
final void clear() {
    mCleared = true;
    // Since clear() is final, this method is still called on mock objects
    // and in those cases, mBagOfTags is null. It'll always be empty though
    // because setTagIfAbsent and getTag are not final so we can skip
    // clearing it
    if (mBagOfTags != null) {
        synchronized (mBagOfTags) {
            for (Object value : mBagOfTags.values()) {
                // see comment for the similar call in setTagIfAbsent
                closeWithRuntimeException(value);
            }
        }
    }
    onCleared();
}

/**
 * Sets a tag associated with this viewmodel and a key.
 * If the given {@code newValue} is {@link Closeable},
 * it will be closed once {@link #clear()}.
 * <p>
 * If a value was already set for the given key, this call does nothing and
 * returns currently associated value, the given {@code newValue} would be ignored
 * <p>
 * If the ViewModel was already cleared then close() would be called on the returned object if
 * it implements {@link Closeable}. The same object may receive multiple close calls, so method
 * should be idempotent.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> T setTagIfAbsent(String key, T newValue) {
    T previous;
    synchronized (mBagOfTags) {
        previous = (T) mBagOfTags.get(key);
        if (previous == null) {
            mBagOfTags.put(key, newValue);
        }
    }
    T result = previous == null ? newValue : previous;
    if (mCleared) {
        // It is possible that we'll call close() multiple times on the same object, but
        // Closeable interface requires close method to be idempotent:
        // "if the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect." (c)
        closeWithRuntimeException(result);
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Returns the tag associated with this viewmodel and the specified key.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({"TypeParameterUnusedInFormals", "unchecked"})
<T> T getTag(String key) {
    if (mBagOfTags == null) {
        return null;
    }
    synchronized (mBagOfTags) {
        return (T) mBagOfTags.get(key);
    }
}

private static void closeWithRuntimeException(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Closeable) {
        try {
            ((Closeable) obj).close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

my ViewModel is in another package.

Comment: The tag objects are internal to the Android implementation and therefore private API. Which means in the future the Android team can change the interface and all of a sudden your app will break.  Are you sure want to use the tags?  Can you clarify why you can not implement an override for onCleared() in your custom ViewModel class, and in your override, just close your closeable interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can set package of your file same as ViewModel package. Write first line of a file: "package androidx.lifecycle"